# How to calculate logarithms in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a Java program that can take values and put them into a formula involving log 1/3.

How can I calculate log 1/3 in Java?

Comment: Do you need natural logarithm? So, you should take a look at [Math::log](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log(double))

Answer (score 9):

When you want to calculate the logarithm you need to know the base. Once you know the base you can perform the calculation:

```
log_b(x) = ln(x) / ln(b)
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base

In Java the [Math#log(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) function calculates the natural logarithm. So you can use this to calculate the logarithm to a given base b:

```
double result = Math.log(x) / Math.log(b);
```

Comment: why the result is different from the result from calculator?

Comment: You need to know which logarithm you want to use. If it's the one to the base of `10`, you need to set `b` as `10`. Your calculator probably uses `e` as the base `b`, so this would be the natural logarithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Math.log(value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) to get log of specific value where value is considered to be in `double`.You can also use [`Math.log10(value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29) to get base 10 log.

*So you can just use*

```
Math.log(1/3.0)
```

Comment: OP's point is correct. He is asking how to calculate `log(1/3)`. Did you try `Math.log(1/3)`?

Answer (score 3):

1/3 yields the result as integer type value. So, the result will be 0, not 0.3333.

Therefore, Math.log(1/3) = Math.log(0), which results in infinity.

So, you need to write Math.log(1/3.0) to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the natural logarithm using the Java.lang.Math.log() method:

```
System.out.println("Math.log(1/3.0)=" + Math.log(1/3.0));
```

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_log.htm and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29

In order to get the log_10 you can do it as follows:

```
System.out.println("log_10(1/3.0)=" + (Math.log(1/3.0)/Math.log(10)));
```

Comment: i used it, but when i calculate this: Math.log(5/2.0), the result is 0.9162907318741551, but when i calculate with my calculator the result is 0.3979xxxx, why it can be different?

Comment: Are you using the `ln`or `log` button on your calculator?

Comment: @MuhammadHaryadiFutra Just type ln 2.5 and log 2.5 into google. You will see both of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new implementation there is inbuilt function for this

Read about [Math.log()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29)

But in this case `log(1/3)` will give you value as `infinity`,If you use `Math.log(1/3)`.

You can use `log` rule as follows.

```
log(1/3) =log(1)-log(3)
```

Now

```
Math.log(1/3)=Math.log(1)-Math.log(3)
```

Eg:

```
System.out.println(Math.log(1)-Math.log(3));
```

Out put:

```
-1.0986122886681098
```